# PHP Advanced Regex Splitting

Tags: php, regex

I'm facing a slight issue with an idea.

I use a chat feature within an online forum on all my computing devices. I also use it mobily, which causes slight issues of formatting, input, etc. I've had the idea to relay all the chat from a relay account to my own mobile friendly site.

I haven't started on sending messages yet, although I know how to read messages. How to output them is the issue.

I sniffed outgoing packets on my computer as the chat uses ajax. I was then able to find the following url: http://server05.ips-chat-service.com/get.php?room=xxxx&user=xxxx&access_key=xxxx

The page outputs something similar to this: `~~||~~1419344231,1,kondaxdesign,Could somebody send a quick message for me__C__ please?,,10248~~||~~1419344237,1,tom.bridges,its a iso and a vm what more do we need to know?,,10880~~||~~`

That string would output this in chat: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7CM6.png

I unfortunately don't have much knowledge on regex, or any other function that would split this. Would anybody be able to assist me on getting the 1). Name, 2). Chat Data and 3). Timestamp?

As you can see, the string is something like this: `~~||~~[timestamp],1,[name],[data],,[some integer]~~||~~`

Cheers.

After reading through the string output, when somebody leaves chat, this is sent: `~~||~~1419344521,2,wegface,TIMEOUT,2_10828,0~~||~~`

The beginning of the log starts with `1,224442` before the first `~~||~~`.

Comment: Can you tell us what each segment means? Or should we just write a script to split and use each segment?

Comment: I'm currently researching information on this, although not much. I had a theory of retrieving the data, splitting on each `~~||~~` and then splitting on each comma.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑI've included an example. Forgot to put it within the code format, sorry. Please check the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) each record, then use [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) to read the string and parse it as you want. Here is a script that does that, without any formatting on output, and I've named the variables as named in the OP that describes what they are.

I wouldn't use a regular expression to parse the string, as better functionality is available (linked above)

```
$string = "~~||~~1419344231,1,kondaxdesign,Could somebody send a quick message for me__C__ please?,,10248~~||~~1419344237,1,tom.bridges,its a iso and a vm what more do we need to know?,,10880~~||~~";

//Split so we have each chat record to loop around
foreach( explode("~~||~~", $string) as $segments) {
    //Read the CSV properly
    $chat = str_getcsv($segments);
    if( count($chat) <> 6 ) { continue; } //Skip any that don't have all the data
    $timestamp = $chat[0];
    $name = $chat[2];
    $data = $chat[3];
    $some_integer = $chat[5];

    echo $name .' said - '. $data .'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I've actually just created an extremely similar approach without the data splitting. Thanks very much, this seems as though it will work great.